# type casting in K&R

Tags: c

K&R provide this `getchar()` example:

```
int getchar(void)
{
    char c;

    return (read(0, &c, 1) == 1) ? (unsigned char) c : EOF;
}
```

`c` is cast to `unsigned char` here to avoid sign extension issues, but in the `fputs()` example...

```
int fputs(char *s, FILE *iop)
{
    int c;

    while (c = *s++)
        putc(c, iop);
    return ferror(iop) ? EOF : 0;
}
```

`*s` is assigned to an `int` without first casting to an `unsigned char`.  Why is the cast unnecessary this time?

Answer (score 3):

It is not about "sign extension issues". This implementation of `getchar` makes sure that all successfully read characters are returned as *non-negative* `int` values. This behavior is required by the specification of `getchar`, which literally says that the character read is returned as `unsigned char` values converted to `int`, even if `char` is signed on the given platform. What you see there is basically a direct implementation of `getchar` spec.

Meanwhile `fputs` does not return any specific character values. `fputs` does not return `c` to the user. That `c` is a purely internal variable. It should preserve the original value of `char` type on the given platform, since the value of `c` is then passed to `putc`. `putc` does not expect character values converted to non-negative range, it expects original character values, which could easily be negative if `char` is signed.

BTW, why did you look at `fputs`, and not `fputc`? If you look at `fputc`, which just like `getchar` returns a character value, you will probably see that it is implemented similarly to `getchar` in that regard.

Comment: Why did I look at `fputs`, and not `fputc`?

There is no `fputc` example given in the book.

Comment: @Derek: Well, fair enough. But again, `fputs` cannot be meaningfully comparet to `getchar` in that regard, since `fputs` return value spec is completely different.

Answer (score 2):

I completely misunderstood the question the first time around. The problem here is that `getchar()` needs to return either a `char` in the entire range 0-255 or `EOF`. On most platforms `EOF = -1`. In order to return both a negative value and a char, int must be used.

This is not the case in `fputs`. In this example, a `char` is being assigned to an `int` in the while loop. "Lower" types are promoted to "higher" types. From page 44 KR, The C Programming Language:

> If either operand is a `long double`, convert the other to a `long double`.
>   Otherwise, if either operand is a `double`, convert the other to a `double`.
>   Otherwise, if either operand is a `float`, convert the other to a `float`.
>   **Otherwise, convert `char` and `short` to `int`**
>   Then, if either operand is a `long`, convert the other to `long`.

Comment: No, `fputs` does accept an int argument. That is the premise of the question.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You mean `putc` takes an `int`. Lower types are promoted to higher types where no unsigned operations are taken place.   No cast is needed here in the while loop. See page 44 in KR, The C Programming Language 2nd Ed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The other premise is that such promotion doesn't necessarily do the right thing; e.g. negative integers do not represent character codes. Such is the reason for the explicit cast in the `getchar`. On the other hand `putc` is defined to accept integer values which aren't character codes, which is confusing (but only to a very eagle-eyed programmer, heck just for that this guy deserves an upvote).

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page,

> The `fputc()` function writes the character `c` (converted to an `unsigned char`) to the output stream pointed to by `stream`.

The cast is specifically performed for you inside the function.

Aside from that, assigning from `char` to negative `int` and back to `char` is guaranteed to produce the correct result, and `char` to negative `int` to `unsigned char` is guaranteed to have the same result as a direct cast from `char` to `unsigned char`. Other cases may produce signed integer overflow, which produces undefined behavior (i.e., could crash). But most platforms handle that by quiet binary truncation, in such a way that many programmers never worry about it at all.